# How to append connection dynamically in database.php file in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, multi-tenant

I need to append dynamically connection in the database.php file using PHP code, is it possible or not?

Comment: Maybe that is helpful: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/generating-dynamic-database-connections-laravel-marshall-oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working for me
When I create a new customer then

```
public function setConnection($tenantName){
    //GET Database Connection file path
            $path = config_path('database.php');
            //GET Database Connection file 
            $arr = include $path;
            // load the array from the file
            $new_connection=[
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
                'database'  => $tenantName,
                'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
                'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
                'strict' => false
            ];
            // modify the array
            $arr['connections'][$tenantName]=$new_connection;
           // write it back to the file
            file_put_contents($path, "<?php  return " . var_export($arr, true) . ";");
    }
```

Comment: Overwriting the config file via `file_put_contents()` looks a little bit hacky to me but if you do this in an artisan command it might make sense to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have multiple database connections and explicitly execute queries on one of them: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections

The config/database.php has to return an array where `config('database.connections')` contains an array with keys representing different database engines but it's totally possible to for example add `mysql2` and `mysql3` to that array.

For example:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$customConnections = [];
for(var $i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $customConnections['mysql'.$i] = [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '330'.$i),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mysql'.$i),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'mysql'.$i),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ];
}

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [
        ...$customConnections,
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'options' => [
                // here you can pass more settings to the Mongo Driver Manager
                // see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php under "Uri Options" for a list of complete parameters that you can use

                'database' => env('DB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', 'admin'), // required with Mongo 3+
            ],
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    // ...

];
```

Comment: I want to add a connection as dynamically when a new customer creates then I need to add a new connection for new customer database in the database.php

Comment: The for-loop is only an example. You can make a query at that position to get all customers and than loop over these.

Comment: Review my posted answer it's work for me. thanks for your response.