# Programmatically edit config/database.php connection

Tags: php, database, laravel, connection, config

I have a SAAS application in which users creates school, now, once that school was approved, I need to automate the creation of that school's database. So far, I can **manually** do it by adding new connection to database.php config. My question is, how can I dynamically add new connection to database.php?

```php
     ...

     'connections' => [

        'tenant2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => 'tenant2',
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'paco97058' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => 'paco97058',
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
      ]
```

I want to add **paco97058** dynamically to the database.php

Please note that **paco97058** is a database name and is automatically created upon creation.

Comment: Database with connection database ??

Comment: Yes, exactly that is.

Comment: Do yo really need different databases for each school?

Comment: Why don't use a super DB with others DB info into that?

Comment: Yes, it's a saas application with multi database. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: The structure is like that @SimoneRossaini

Comment: I got that. But by question was if you really _need_ multiple databases? The fact that it's a SaaS application is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: The purpose is for the migration and seeder to work.

Comment: I use spatie package here https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/installation/using-multiple-databases

Comment: Does that answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602130/how-to-append-connection-dynamically-in-database-php-file-in-laravel/67603472#67603472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using the method below, thanks @shaedrich.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$connections = [];
$tenants = DB::connection('landlord')->table('tenants')->where('status', 'Approved')->get();

foreach ($tenants as $tenant) {
    $connections[$tenant->database] = [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => $tenant->database,
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ];
}

return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION'),

    'connections' => [

        'tenant' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => null,
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'landlord' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        $connections,

    ],
```

I have fetch the $tenant->database first, then use foreach loop to store connection to array.

Comment: That looks like a solid way to solve this. What I would suggest to do is only register the connection of the tenant that you are using in that request, instead of registering a connection for all tenants.